# got error when I am running Jar file. IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I am developing Javafx app with maven. I can run my app from Intellij idea without any exception and error. But I got error when I am running Jar file. How to solve that issue?

I think, the below exception got at that line:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("../screen/AdminScreen.fxml"));
```

Help me, please?

This is my exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set. 
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459) 
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435) 
    at login.LoginController.signInAction(LoginController.java:101) 
    at login.LoginController.lambda$addListeners$2(LoginController.java:65)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49) 
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198) 
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
```

Comment: Try removing `..` from your resource path.

Comment: Sorry about that it doesn't work for me!

Comment: Show your project structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `..` is not a valid Java identifier, there is no guarantee of this getting resolvable. Try following:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/screen/AdminScreen.fxml"))
```

Alternatively , the following link explains java resources usage: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I already found solution. I should add getClassLoader method.

Comment: @NyamkhuuBuyanjargal no, you don't need to use the classLoader method - read up on how resources are looked up (in the api doc!)  and follow the spec

Comment: @salsinga that docs doesn't help me. when I running Jar file, that solution doesn't work for me. So what do I do?

Comment: I see. My fault sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("../screen/AdminScreen.fxml"));
```

To This:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("AdminScreen.fxml"));
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I already tried it!, But I found solution :D just a moment.